# Foundation toggle off-canvas menu

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, show-hide

The toggle function works on small screens, but when using a larger screen the toggle function does not show/hide the container.

Is there a way to make the container show by default on large screens but also be able to show and hide the container with button click using Foundation?

Container:

```
<div class="off-canvas position-left reveal-for-large is-transition-push" 
  id="mainSidebar" 
  data-off-canvas 
  data-position="left" 
  aria-hidden="false">Content goes here.</div>
```

Button:

```
<button class="menu-icon" 
  type="button" 
  data-open="mainSidebar" 
  aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-controls="mainSidebar">Toggle container</button>
```

Comment: By removing `reveal-for-large` the show/hide feature works on all screen sizes, however the desired functionality is to be revealed on large screens by default.

Answer (score 0):

### Toggle off-canvas menu for all device.

**CSS Code**

```
<style>

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body>

<div id="sideNav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#"> Our Services</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
  <a href="#">Login Up</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
</div>
```

**JS Script to open and close the toggle**

```
 <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
 </script>

</body>
```

Comment: That's not Fundation Zurb. Thanks for sharing the snippet anyways.